# What is the performance overhead of using a Python ORM to query a DB of objects?

Tags: python, database, class, oop, orm

I'm trying to learn OOP on my own and I'm trying to understand when to use classes.

If I have a class called User, that has a couple different methods...etc.  Now let's say I have 50,000 users in my db that I want to query for reporting. And let's say I want to pull the ids of half of the users based on a User class attribute.

Does that mean an instance of the class is created 50,000 times?  If so, doesn't that slow things down vs having a stand alone function that does the query?

Comment: This is not really about objects per se, but about **the overhead (e.g. of an ORM), when doing a DB query**. Really you're asking *"if using an ORM creates an object instance for every record, is its overhead too heavy?"* There are other ways to represent your Users, such as a SQL table/ DB/ schema (sqlite/ MySQL/ Postgres/ etc.), or Django, or a No-SQL DB. Ultimately what is your code trying to do? Do you need to use Python and what are the other system requirements (a GUI? REST interface? CPU and memory demands)? If you can do this in one line of SQL, then why not just do it all in SQL?

Comment: There are 59 existing questions on [**python ORM overhead**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+ORM+overhead), probably this is a duplicate. Also there are lots of existing articles out there **"Should I use an ORM?"** Unless you tell us your system requirements, only you can answer this for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question.  But if you're asking whether you can use methods in a class without instantiating (i.e. creating an instance of) the class, then the answer is yes. You have to use a concept called "static methods."

Consider this class, Foo:

```
class Foo():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def say_hello(self):
        print('Hello from Foo!')
```

In order to call the `say_hello` method, we must do the following:

```
f = Foo()
f.say_hello()
```

This prints `Hello from Foo!` in the console.

However, in order to get this to work, we had to create an `__init__` method, and we had to instantiate Foo.  Let us repeat this experiment now using static methods with the `@staticmethod` decorator.

```
class Foo():

    @staticmethod
    def say_hello():
        print('Hello from Foo!')


Foo.say_hello()
```

This prints `Hello from Foo!` in the console and did not require the creation of any object.  As you can see, no `__init__` (i.e. constructor) was required.

I hope this helped, and I apologize if I missed the mark of your question.  Best of luck to you!

Comment: This is great!  Thank you so much.  I'm just trying to figure out how to employ the principles of OPP.  I'm trying to figure out when to employ classes.  Should there be a class for users and a class for the report itself...etc.  You answer is very helpful.